# access value in a model in Django

Tags: python, django

i'm started to learn django a week ago and I'm trying get the bid_value from a model in django but it return this error:

> AttributeError at /item/2 'QuerySet' object has no attribute
> 'bid_value'

I tried a few ways, but it didn't work

models.py:

```
class Auction_listings(models.Model):
    product_image = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_category = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="others")
    product_price = models.FloatField()
    is_closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product_title}"


class Bids(models.Model):
    auction = models.ForeignKey(Auction_listings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    bid_value = models.FloatField()
```

views.py:

```
def add_bid(request, item_id):
    username = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        username = request.user.username

    if request.method == "POST":
        bid = Bids.objects.filter(auction=item_id).bid_value

        new_bid_value = float(request.POST.get("bid"))
        if new_bid_value > float(bid):
            new_bid = Bids(auction=item_id, username=username, bid_value=new_bid_value)
            new_bid.save()
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/error.html", {
                "error": "your bid is lower than the current bid..."
            })

def view_item(request, id):
    item_id = Auction_listings.objects.get(pk=id)
    add_bid(request, item_id)
    try:
        bid = Bids.objects.get(auction=item_id)

        return render(request, "auctions/item.html", {
                "auctions": item_id,
                "bid": bid
        })
    except:
        return render(request, "auctions/item.html", {
            "auctions": item_id,
        })
```

thank you in advanced

Comment: `Bids.objects.filter(auction=item_id).bid_value` makes no sense, since this is a set (collection) of `Bids` objects, not a single `Bid` object.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `bid_value` property of `QuerySet`, not the model.

And you are trying to get the value from a list. Since `auction` property of `Bids` model is a `ForeignKeyField`, the query returns a list, not a single instance. You need to get the maximum value from `Bids.objects`

```
if request.method == "POST":
        bid = Bids.objects.filter(auction=item_id).aggregate(Max('bid_value'))['bid_value__max']

        .....
```

Answer (score 0):

The clue as to why your code is failing is of course, in the error.

*"AttributeError at /item/2 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'bid_value'"*

Your error lies here:

```
bid = Bids.objects.filter(auction=item_id).bid_value
```

With Bids.objects.filter(auction=item_id) you're creating a Queryset object.
I like [this explanation from djangogirls](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/):
"A QuerySet is, in essence, a list of objects of a given Model. QuerySets allow you to read the data from the database, filter it and order it."

You need to access the bid_value attribute on a model. So one way to do this would be to get the first value returned from the queryset:

```
bid = Bids.objects.filter(auction=item_id).first().bid_value
```

A better way would be to check if the object exists, and then access the bid_value attribute:

```
bid = Bids.objects.filter(auction=item_id).first()
if bid:
    bid = bid.bid_value
```

Happy learning! :)